# Dependent Field angularjs - ng-show

Tags: angularjs, html, ng-show, ng-hide

I would like to create dependent fields. Please see the code below:

```
<div class="s-12 l-10"><select ng-model="requestType" required="required">
        <option value="" disabled selected style="display: none;">Request Type</option>
        <?php
        $result = DB::getInstance()->get('vwcustomfieldsoptions',array('id','=',16705));
        foreach($result->results() as $result)
        { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $result->customvalue ?>"><?php echo $result->customvalue ?></option>
       <?php } 
       ?>
    </select>
</div><div class="s-12 l-10"><select ng-show="requestType =='Work Request' " ng-model="workRequestType" required="required">
        <option value="" disabled selected style="display: none;">Work Request Type</option>
        <?php
        $result = DB::getInstance()->get('vwcustomfieldsoptions',array('id','=',16706));
        foreach($result->results() as $result)
        { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $result->customvalue ?>"><?php echo $result->customvalue ?></option>
       <?php } 
       ?>
    </select>
</div>
 </div><div class="s-12 l-10"><select ng-show="workRequestType =='Amendments to existing code'" ng-model="output" required="required">
        <option value="" disabled selected style="display: none;">Output</option>
        <?php
        $result = DB::getInstance()->get('vwcustomfieldsoptions',array('id','=',16711));
        foreach($result->results() as $result)
        { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $result->customvalue ?>"><?php echo $result->customvalue ?></option>
       <?php } 
       ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

So, when the user selects '**Work Required**' from the the `requestType` dropdown, the `workRequestType` dropdown appears. Now I would like to do the same thing for the following field. When the user selects '**Amendments to existing code**' from on the '**Amendments to existing code**' the `output` dropdown should appear. For some reason its not working for this field.  I'm a newbie to angularjs.

Comment: did you check my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may helps you and solve your problem. Please try following snippet.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
    $scope.names1 = ["Blue", "Green", "Red"];
    $scope.names2 = ["Gold", "Silver", "Brownze"];
  
    $scope.callSelect1 = function(){
      $scope.select2 = $scope.select1;
    }
    
    $scope.callSelect2 = function(){
      $scope.select3 = $scope.select2;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="select1" ng-options="x for x in names" ng-change="callSelect1()">
</select>
  

<select ng-show="select1 == 'Linus'" ng-model="select2" ng-options="x for x in names1" change="callSelect2()">
</select>
  
<select ng-show="select2 == 'Green'"  ng-model="select3"  ng-options="x for x in names2">
</select>
 

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I still find it strange that my code is not working.  I really don't get it or does a third dependent change require it's own scope ? Meaning if I add a fourth dependent field that depends on the 3rd one I will need to add another scope ?

Comment: @kya: Yes same way what is done for select2 and select3